# How to correctly initialize database in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jdbc, utf-8, spring-jdbc

I want to initialize database when application is starting.
In root-context.xml I add this jdbc:initialize-database

```
<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
    <jdbc:script location="/WEB-INF/import.sql" />
</jdbc:initialize-database>
```

My dataSource

```
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />

    </bean>
```

and jdbc.properties

```
jdbc.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
jdbc.username=postgres
jdbc.password=z123456z
jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/answer?charSet=UTF8
```

I use PostgreSQL 9.2.
In database I have "РЎС‚СЂСѓРєС‚СѓСЂР° РґР°РЅРёС…" instead of "Алгоритм".

How to correctly specify this option and solve problem ?

Comment: Is it possible you are using the wrong character encoding?

Comment: @CodeChimp `import.sql` has utf-8 encoding

Comment: Is the DB setup to use utf-8? What is getting set to "РЎС‚СЂСѓРєС‚СѓСЂР° РґР°РЅРёС…" instead of "Алгоритм", the database name, the table name, the field name, some value in some field in some table in some database? From the surface, if you have a string "abcdefg" and you try to put it in a DB, but it ends up as "@#$sdf23", then it is probably a character encoding issue.

Comment: Yes, DB is setup to use utf-8. My sql code for creating database
`CREATE DATABASE answer
  WITH OWNER = postgres
       ENCODING = 'UTF8'
       TABLESPACE = pg_default
       LC_COLLATE = 'Ukrainian_Ukraine.1251'
       LC_CTYPE = 'Ukrainian_Ukraine.1251'
       CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;`

Comment: It's hard for me to say 100%, but I have a sneaky suspision its related to the locale of 'Ukrainian_Ukraine.1251'.

Comment: I changed postgresql to mysql (5.6 version)
I created database using this script `create database if not exists answer DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf8 default COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;` 
My jdbc `jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/answer?characterEncoding=utf8&useUnicode=true`.
The problems has remained.

Comment: Maybe its the code, then.  All I can say is if you are reading "ABC" and end up with "XYZ", there is something doing a conversion somewhere. If you are 100% sure you are not modifying the values anywhere, then my gut intuition is that something is doing it for you, and in my experience that has usually came down to character encodings/conversions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use follow:

```
<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
    <jdbc:script location="/WEB-INF/import.sql" encoding="UTF-8" />
</jdbc:initialize-database>
```